# Query 2 tables join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I want to get all the films whose genre is equal to `ID_GENRE = 8`. This is the query that I'm doing:

http://l4c.me/fullsize/2-tablas-1434140362.png

```
$query_GetSimilar = sprintf("SELECT * FROM z_movie,z_movie_genre ORDER BY z_movie.visits DESC WHERE z_movie_genre.id_genre = 8 LIMIT 18");
$GetSimilar = mysql_query($query_GetSimilar, conect::dbconect()) or die(mysql_error());
$row_GetSimilar = mysql_fetch_assoc($GetSimilar);
$totalRows_GetSimilar = mysql_num_rows($GetSimilar);
```

But I jump the next error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE z_movie_genre.id_genre = 8 LIMIT 18' at line 1

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE  ... ORDER`, not `SELECT ... ORDER  ... WHERE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Note:

- `WHERE` should be first before `ORDER BY`
- You can use `INNER JOIN` to get two connecting tables, assuming that they have connecting id/column.

For example, both `z_movie` and `z_movie_genre` table has the column `id_genre` to connect each other, you can try this:

```
$query_GetSimilar = sprintf("SELECT * FROM z_movie
                               INNER JOIN z_movie_genre ON z_movie.id_genre = z_movie_genre.id_genre
                               WHERE z_movie_genre.id_genre = 8
                               ORDER BY z_movie.visits DESC
                               LIMIT 18");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple search, and see if you can put 'order by' before 'where'.

Answer (score 0):

ok, now my query is:

```
$query_GetSimilar = sprintf("SELECT * FROM z_movie,z_movie_genre WHERE z_movie_genre.id_genre=8  ORDER BY z_movie.visits DESC LIMIT 18");
$GetSimilar = mysql_query($query_GetSimilar, conect::dbconect()) or die(mysql_error());
$row_GetSimilar = mysql_fetch_assoc($GetSimilar);
$totalRows_GetSimilar = mysql_num_rows($GetSimilar);
```

but I do not have the expected results

Comment: Only needed to add the next: "SELECT * FROM z_movie JOIN z_movie_genre ON z_movie.id = z_movie_genre.id_movie WHERE z_movie_genre.id_genre=8  ORDER BY z_movie.visits DESC LIMIT 18"